# Start $interval immediately in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have the function `notifications.get()` that runs every 10 seconds.

```
function notificationsCtrl($scope, $interval) {
    $interval(function(){ 
        $scope.notification = notifications.get();
        $('.card').addClass('rotate');
    }, 10000);
};
```

But when the page is loaded, the function should be called once immediately.
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can do it like this,

1. Define it as a function
2. Call it immediately by function name
3. Attach function to `$interval()` for execute in every 10 sec.

**CODE:**

```
function notificationsCtrl($scope, $interval) {
    var fun = function(){ 
        $scope.notification = notifications.get();
        $('.card').addClass('rotate');
    };
    fun();
    $interval(fun, 10000);
};
```

Comment: What if you need to cancel the interval within fun?

Comment: @adamdport : you can use `$interval.cancel()`, for eg: `var int = $interval(fun, 10000);  $interval.cancel(int)`

Answer (score 4):

you can use $interval.flush(millis) to move forward by millis milliseconds and trigger any functions scheduled to run in that time.